# Python Tool/package which generates quiz from questions and answers options from text file

Tags: java, python, algorithm

I have a text file which has 30 multiple choice questions in the following pattern

1. question one goes here ?

   A. Option 1

   B. Option 2

   C. Option 3

   D. Option 4

and so on to 30

Number of options is variable; there are minimum two and maximum six options.

I want to practice these questions in a interface like html/php quiz which allows me to select options and at last displays the result.

I tried reading the file in python and then tried to store questions and answers in separate lists but it did not work.
Below is my code:

```
#to prevent IndexError 
question = ['','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','']
answers = ['','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','']
qOrA = "q"
mcq_file = "mcqs.txt"
mcq = open(mcq_file, "r")
data_list = mcq.readlines()

for i in range(len(data_list)):
    element = list(data_list[i])
    if element[0] == "A" and element[1] == ".":
        qOrA = "a"

    if qOrA == "q":
        question[i] = question[i]+ " " + data_list[i]

    elif qOrA == "a":
        answers[i] = answers[i]+ " " + data_list[i]
```

mcq.readlines() output upto question no. 3 is given below
Note: Actually there are multiple line breaks so the file is not properly structured.

```
['ï»¿\n', '1.\n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', 'Which computer component contains all the \n', '\n', 'circuitry necessary for all components or \n', '\n', 'devices to communicate with each other?\n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', 'A.â€¯Motherboard\n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', 'B.â€¯Hard Drive\n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', 'C.â€¯Expansion Bus\n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', 'D.â€¯Adapter Card\n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '2. \n', '\n', 'Which case type is typically \n', '\n', 'used for servers?\n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', 'A.\n', '\n', 'â€¯\n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', 'Mini Tower\n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', 'B.\n', '\n', 'â€¯\n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', 'Mid Tower\n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', 'C.\n', '\n', 'â€¯\n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', 'Full Tower\n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', 'D.\n', '\n', 'â€¯\n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', 'desktop\n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '3.\n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', 'What is the most reliable way for users to buy the \n', '\n', 'correct RAM to upgrade a computer?\n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', 'A.\n', '\n', 'â€¯\n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', 'Buy RAM that is the same color as the memory sockets \n', '\n', 'on the motherboard.\n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', 'B.\n', '\n', 'â€¯\n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', 'Ensure that the RAM chip is the same size as the ROM chip.\n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', 'C.\n', '\n', 'â€¯\n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', 'Ensure that the RAM is \n', '\n', 'compatible\n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', 'with the peripherals \n', '\n', 'installed on the motherboard.\n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', 'D.\n', '\n', 'â€¯\n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', 'Check the motherboard manual or manufacturerâ€™s website.\n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', ' \n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n']
```

Comment: what mcq_file containing?

Comment: @Harsha It contains 30 multiple choice questions and answers in the format

`1. question one goes here ?

`A. Option 1

`B. Option 2

`C. Option 3

`D. Option 4

`2. question two goes here ?

`A. Option 1

`B. Option 2

`C. Option 3

`D. Option 4


and so on to 30

Comment: and where answer for that question is stored?

Comment: list variable called "answers"

Comment: so whats the problem? could you please rearrange the question to get clearly about what your desire output and what you are getting?

Comment: I want to store all question in a list variable called question and all answers in answers so that I get the data in variables, I can then make quiz program

Comment: @BrainyPrb, please show us a couple lines stored in `data_list = mcq.readlines()`.

Comment: @srig I have added data_list = mcq.readlines() above, please check. And My file has 30 questions in total , those questions have unordered line breaks but all answers start with A. or a. so they can be identified uniquely and questions always start with 1. , 2. and soon

Comment: @BrainyPrb, with the text you shared at [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Gje4APBH), so far I've come up with [this](https://repl.it/repls/TeemingComplicatedTick) and I'm stopping here as I'm in a rush. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
question =[]
mcq = open(mcq_file, "r")
data_list = mcq.readlines()  
for data in data_list:
    data = data.strip() #removes white space
    first_part = data.split(".")[0] 
    if first_part.isnumeric():
        # This is question and you can append this in question list
        question.append(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this does what you want. There are some minor mistakes because the formatting in the mcqs.txt is unpredictably inconsistent. For example, in question 5 the answers appear out of order. We exchange one evil for another when we choose to accommodate for the lower case answer choices of question 26, this is why question 3 answer choices look strange ("website." and "motherboard." end with "e." and "d.") . Likewise, question 25, is written 2 \n 5. this is why separate words are occasionally concatenated in the output. I'm very curious to know what format the original document was in and why it is so mangled? Are these typos or did you paste from a PDF or something?

```
#Get text into workable format
txt=open(r"mcqs.txt","r").readlines()
txt=[line.replace("\n"," ") for line in txt]
txt=[line for line in txt if len(line)>0]
txt=[line.encode('ascii','ignore').decode("utf-8") for line in txt]
txt=[line.strip() for line in txt if line!=" " and line!=""]
txt1="".join(txt)     
#Initialize Separator lists
full_test,q_list,let_list=dict(),[str(i)+"." for i in range(1,31)],["A","B","C","D","E","F"]
def segment(txt1,list_of_separators):
    #Returns list of tuples
    #Tuples define start and end index of separator
    i,j,ints,ends=0,0,[],[]
    while j<len(list_of_separators):
        sep=list_of_separators[j]
        if sep in txt1[i:i+len(sep)+1] or sep.lower() in txt1[i:i+len(sep)+1]:
            index=i+len(sep)
            if txt1[i+len(sep)]==".": index=index+1
            ints.append(index)
            ends.append(len(sep))
            j=j+1
        if i==len(txt1):
            break
        i=i+1
    ints=ints+[len(txt1)+ends[-1]]
    tups = [(ints[k],ints[k+1]-ends[k]) for k in range(len(ints)-1)]
    return tups
#Segment based on question number
tups=segment(txt1,q_list)
#Get blocks of text (includes question and answer choices)
blocks,n=[txt1[tup[0]:tup[1]].strip() for tup in tups],1
for block in blocks:
    #Segment based on answer choice
    tups=segment(block,[str(i)+"." for i in let_list])
    tups=[(0,tups[0][0]-2)]+tups
    choices=[block[tup[0]:tup[1]].strip() for tup in tups]
    #Initialize dictionary
    full_test[n]={"Question":choices[0]}
    m=0
    for choice in choices[1:]:
        full_test[n].update({let_list[m]+".":choice})
        m=m+1
    n=n+1
#Prompt user for answer as if actually test
for question in full_test.keys():
    print(str(question)+"."+full_test[question]["Question"]+"\n")
    ind=0
    for choice in full_test[question].items():
        if ind==0:
            ind=ind+1
            continue
        else:
            print(choice[0]+" "+choice[1])
    answer=input("\nAnswer:")
    full_test[question].update({"Answer":answer})
```

If I wasn't feeling up for the challenge, I would have just fixed the minor inconsistencies in format and probably would have come up with something simpler. But what's the fun in that...

Comment: actually the file in not properly ordered so we cannot expect "?" sign on end of line , so this implementation won't work

Comment: Ok... you can replace 'if "?" in txt[i]' with 'if txt[i].split(".")[0].isnumeric()... depending on if answers are tabbed, txt[i].startswith("   ")==False might work as well

Comment: What do you mean not properly ordered?

Comment: not properly ordered means there are unnecessary line breaks, everything else is fine. Replacing with given statement is also not working, now its not gettings questions

Comment: Can you post an actual excerpt of mcqs.txt?

Comment: I have pasted it here (it has 30 questions)
https://pastebin.com/Gje4APBH